# If i have a mongo document id as a string how do I query for it as an _id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If i have a mongo document id as a string how do I query for it as an _id?

Will it work correctly to do `.find({_id:'stringID'})` or do I need to convert it to a bson object first?

Comment: Your `_id` can be **anything** (except for array). So yes, string _ids are fine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Do you mean you have the 24 hex digit string of an ObjectId?

Assuming that's what you mean, most drivers have a way to take a string and convert it to an ObjectId. In JavaScript that's:

```
.find({_id:new ObjectId("4f91bfcfaa7c5687a0c686d4")})
```

**Updated** to be a bit more useful for the node-native driver (from the documentation at https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native):

```
// Get the objectID type
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var idString = '4e4e1638c85e808431000003';
collection.findOne({_id: new ObjectID(idString)}, console.log)  // ok
collection.findOne({_id: idString}, console.log)  // wrong! callback gets undefined
```

Comment: Yes, you understand my question. Sorry probably wasn't worded well, `_id`s are default mongo bson objects. They get mutated when sending json to the client so they are being converted to strings first. When they get back to the server I need to turn them back into objects to query the database with them?

Comment: Yeah, to query you need to convert them to `ObjectId`s again.

Comment: btw, it looks like some of mongoose's functions automatically cast to ObjectId, like if you do findById. Saw one of your other questions mentioned mongoose.

Comment: Yea, I don't actually like mongoose at all. I'm just using the standard node-native lib.

Comment: @EveFreeman I've a part of the objectid string, and would like to query it in mongo shell, how can I do that

Answer (score 3):

If your _id values are strings, you may query them just like any other field.  (Just remember, if you are setting custom values for _id, they must be kept unique, or you will get a duplicate key error. )

Here is an example in the Mongo JS Shell:

```
> db.test.insert({_id:"stringID1"})
> db.test.insert({_id:"stringID2"})
> db.test.insert({_id:"stringID3"})
> db.test.find({_id:"stringID1"})
{ "_id" : "stringID1" }
>
```

Is this what you were looking for?  I hope I did not misunderstand your question!

Comment: This actually answers the **asked** question, but apparently not the question she **meant to ask** ^^

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose auto casts the string `_id` to ObjectId when you use `findByID`, so you can query using the string `_id`.

Also remember that any input coming into your API from `req.body` or `req.params` will all be type string so you will need to type cast if needed..., but as mentioned, mongoose does that for you so you can just leave `_id` in the string format it comes in as.

Comment: Now this was a really helpful answer!

Comment: I have userId in string,I am using that in findByIdAndUpdate(userId,{}),but it gives error,is it correct or I have to convert.