# Express MongoDB find() based on _id field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

So In my express app, I am trying to find() based on my _id field.

**See my MongoDB record below.**

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a"
        },
        "title": "EntertheBadJah",
        "subTitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "thmbNailImg": "",
        "headerImg": "",
         ... BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

When I use `.find( _id: id )`, 
my `id` param = `58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a`.

How would I convert / use this to get my MongoDB record?

**Here is my Express call:**

```
//GET ARTICLE
app.get('/api/article', (req, res) => {

    var id = req.query.id
    var article = [];

    db.collection('articles')
        .find( _id: id )
        .then(result => {
            article = articles.concat(result);
        }).then(() => {
            res.send(article);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });

});
```

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: (my revised query)**

```
//GET ARTICLE
app.get('/api/article', (req, res) => {

    var id = req.query.id

    db.collection('articles').findOne({
        "_id.$oid": id
    }, function(err, article) {
        res.send(article);
        console.log(article)
    });

});
```

> article is Currently returning NULL.

Comment: try this, `db.collection('articles').find( {"_id.$oid": id })`  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document/#embedded-documents

Comment: Just tried, it returns "MongoError: query selector must be an object" @ajaiJothi

Comment: updated my answer. Please check now

Comment: @danjonescidtrix When you say "_58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a as an integer_", is that right - an integer? Is that supposed to be a string?

Comment: it is an integer, should it be a string in my query? @VinceBowdren

Comment: What integer is it? "58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a" appears to be a string.

Comment: ahh it will be a string then.. see my edit on the question @VinceBowdren

Comment: any ideas man? :) @VinceBowdren

Comment: You need to cast your string "58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a" to an ObjectId. I don't know the express environment at all, but it may be as simple as `ObjectId(req.query.id)`.

Comment: what is the request url?

Comment: axios.get('/api/article', {
                params: {
                    id: id
                }
            })  ...but I dont think my problem lies in the request @NERDYLIZARD

Comment: try `/api/article?id="yourid"` for query.

Comment: I dont think my problem is the query, when I log 'req.query.id' it returns 58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a, I just dont know how to return my record for that _id @NERDYLIZARD

Comment: @danjonescidtrix I dug a bit deeper from another source. See edit, hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db.collection('articles')
    .find( {"_id.$oid": id} )
    .
```

or even more specific:

```
db.collection('articles')
    .findOne( {"_id.$oid": id} )
    .
```

**EDIT:**
Converting string into ObjectId type before querying

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;   
db.collection('articles')
    .findOne( {"_id.$oid": new ObjectID(id)})
    .
```

Reference: [If i have a mongo document id as a string how do I query for it as an _id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253972/if-i-have-a-mongo-document-id-as-a-string-how-do-i-query-for-it-as-an-id)

Answer (score 0):

for me `"_id.$oid"` didn't work. I had to use `"_id"` as shown in following code snippet.

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

...
collection.findOne({ "_id": ObjectId(req.params['id']) })
  .then(...)
```